# Prove that for a 2-form $\omega$ on $Tp\mathbb{R}^3$ there are linearly independent vectors $V_1, V_2$ s.t $\omega(V_1,V_2) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis, differential-forms

I need to better understand a proof for an exercise from Bachmans "[A Geometric Approach to Differential Forms](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0306194v1.pdf)". It ask...

> Exercise 2.16 - Prove that for a 2-form $\omega$ on $Tp\mathbb{R}^3$ there are linearly independent vectors $V_1, V_2$ s.t $\omega(V_1,V_2) = 0$.

When the problem was graded the grader let me know that part of my set-up was correct but I they didn't specify which part and aren't available for discussion between now and the final, and neither is the professor. Any tips or walk-thoughts would be greatly appreciated! Ok, so here's what I have.

$\omega = a(dx\wedge dy) + b(dy\wedge dz) + c(dx\wedge dz)$
we know that
$a(dx\wedge dy) = a(<dx>\times<dy>)\cdot(V_1\times V_2)$

$b(dy\wedge dz) = b(<dy>\times<dz>)\cdot(V_1\times V_2)$

$c(dx\wedge dz) = c(<dx>\times<dz>)\cdot(V_1\times V_2)$
Without loss of generality let $a,b \neq 0$ and let $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ be such that $V_1 \times V_2 = \lambda_1(<dx>\times <dy>) + \lambda_2(<dy>\times <dz>) = 0 $

Geometrically this means that we chose $V_1$ and $V_2$ which are perpendicular to the plane $\omega$ represents.

After that I got stuck and to be honest the grader seemed like he was in a hurry so I'm not sure how solid his notes on that problem are. Thanks again and good luck to everyone who has finals this and next month!

Comment: typing it out seems like I should have made $V_1$ and $V_2$ to be a vectors in the span of two vectors that are perpendicular to the plane that $\omega$ makes in $\mathbb{R}^3$ but I'm not totally sure how to write that algebraically.

Comment: I have no idea what $\langle dx\rangle \times \langle dy\rangle$ means. And your equations don't make sense, as the left-hand side is a $2$-form and the right-hand side is evaluating, presumably, on $(V_1, V_2)$.  And I have no idea what the last sentence $V_1\times V_2 = \dots$ means.

Comment: I've been told that this book uses notation some aren't used to. I linked a pdf to the text if that helps.

Comment: Oh, ugh. You should incorporate the notation into your question. So for a $1$-form $\omega$ on $\Bbb R^3$,  $\langle \omega\rangle$ is the vector $V$ so that $\omega(W) = V\cdot W$ for all vectors $W$. So are you saying that $dx\wedge dy(V,W) = (\langle dx\rangle \times \langle dy\rangle)\cdot (V\times W)$? This is correct, and is based on the same observation as my solution. But still, you need to make your equations correct.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll take a stab at it and post what I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a hint for a correct solution. If we evaluate $\omega=a\,dy\wedge dz + b\,dz\wedge dx + c\,dx\wedge dy$ (note that I've changed the orders of things) on the pair of vectors $V_1,V_2$, this will be the determinant of the $3\times 3$ matrix whose columns are $W,V_1,V_2$, where $W$ is the vector $(a,b,c)$. This in turn can be computed as $W\cdot (V_1\times V_2)$. Why? Can you solve the problem now? (This now sounds very close to what you were saying.)

Comment: I feel like I'm drowning in the notation. So I"ll try to explain it with words and if that makes sense I'll go back and figure out how to write it out using the notation from this text. 

Given a plane described by $\omega$ let $l$ be a line on $\omega$. Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be two vectors perpendicular to $l$ that have an angle between them which is not $0 $ or $ \pi$. The determinant of a vector on $l$ and $V_1$ and $V_2$ is the signed volume of a two dimensional parallelogram in $\mathbb{R}^3$ which of course has signed volume $0$.

Comment: Ok I have a better attempt. Reinterpreting the problem as $W \cdot (V_1 \times V_2)$ the solution is a pair of vectors such that $(W \times V_1) = 0$ and $(V_2 \times W) = 0$. We know such vectors exists by the continuity of the vector space of $T_p\mathbb{R}^3$. Does that make more sense?

Comment: Continuity of the vector space makes no sense; functions are continuous.  You just want $V_i$ in the plane orthogonal to $W$.

Comment: Ah OK, I was trying to find a way to say "such a $V_1$ and $V_2$ must exist". I'm trying to get used to verifying that something can exist after I conclude that a certain type of thing is the solution to a problem. Sounds like it's enough to say that if we have a vector $W$ there is a plane orthogonal to it, and follow that up by describing $V_1$ and $V_2$ as I did in the previous comment and maybe specifying that we can find $V_i's$ that are not linearly independent in that plane. I know a lot of this will sound obvious to you but I'm still learning the language of mathematics, sorry.

Comment: No need to apologize. I just want to alert you to proper language. At some point, check out my lectures on differential forms, not to mention linear algebra and multivariable calculus. See my profile for the link.